# Need an efficient way to get rid of my duplicate HTML code in multiple HTML files

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm currently busy with creating a login form that slides down when a certain login button gets pressed. I've got this working by using the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    $('.loginButton').click(function(){
        $('.login').slideToggle();
    });
});
```

The HTML I made for the login form looks like this:

```
    <main>
        <div class="login">
            <h5>Log in here</h5>
            <form>
              <label for="username">Username:</label>
              <input type="text" id="username" required>
              <label for="password">Password:</label>
              <input type="password" id="password" required>
              <p class="registertext">Click <a href="register.html">here</a> to register!</p>
              <input type="submit" value="Sign in">
            </form>
        </div>
    </main>
```

The problem I stumble upon now is that my website currently uses four HTML pages. So in each of the HTML files of them the above HTML code is present. Now I want to get rid of this duplicate code, but I don't really know what's a good and efficient way to do this. I've already tried some things myself that worked, but I'm not sure whether they are efficient. The first thing I did was appending the HTML code inside the div to the div once the login button gets pressed, I only let this happen once by the once of a Boolean.

```
var firstTime = true;

$(document).ready(function (){
    $('.loginButton').click(function(){
        if (firstTime)      {
            $('.login').append('<h5>Log in here</h5><form><label for="username">Username:</label><input type="text" id="username" required><label for="password">Password:</label><input type="password" id="password" required><p class="registertext">Click <a href="register.html">here</a> to register!</p><input type="submit" value="Sign in"></form>');
        firstTime = false }
    $('.login').slideToggle();
    });
});
```

Another solution I found was putting the code within the div inside a separate HTML file and load that file into the div.

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    $('.login').load(login.html);
    $('.loginButton').click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('active');
        $('.login').slideToggle();
    });
});
```

Comment: The best way to handle this is to use some kind of server interface, such as PHP or NodeJS/pug templates.

Comment: If you don't want to use some kind of template engine, then use the jQuery `load()` method, as in your example. Just don't forget, this method is async

Comment: try http://reactrb.org  you can write replace your html with module reactive components written in ruby.  No server side templates or anything needed to get started.

Answer (score 0):

Mixing HTML and JS is a bad principle; Doing lots of explicit DOM manipulation or HTML strings in JS is bad (hard to read/maintain).

You need a server-side technology to do templating (within Java, PHP, Ruby, ...) or you could use a client-side technology like React or AngularJS.